# How to add lines usning '-' in python Requests

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working with python Requests in Django and I need a similar functionality to the 'quote_plus' module, I need my words to be joined by a '-' instead of '+'. Is there a module for that? If not then how do i do it?

Edit: Giving more info

I have a form_data, for example 'i ate it'
I need to process this form data to get 'i-ate-it', and then add this into a url.

Doing this with Requests would be like:

```
from requests import quote_plus

form_data = 'i ate it'
new_data = quote_plus(form_data)
print(new_data)
```

this would print `i+ate+it` but I need it to be `i-ate-it`

Comment: Can you give us some more info?

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi iscream you can do this

```
from requests import quote_plus

form_data = 'i ate it'
new_data = quote_plus(form_data)
new_data.replace("+", "-")
print(new_data)
```

In case you want to requote the uri, you can do this also

```
from requests.utils import requote_uri
url = "https://www.yoururl.com/i ate it"
requote_uri(url)

'https://www.somerandom.com/i%20ate%20it'
```